# Enable usage of mobile data while connected to a WiFi without internet connection

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, mobile-network, android-10

It is possible to allow my device to use mobile data while connected to a WiFi hotspot?

The reason being is that the WiFi hotspot I connect to does not have an internet connection. So I want to be able to access the internet while still being connected to this WiFi network.

I can see that after Android 10, there is a feature called dual acceleration which allows this for certain app like Instagram, Chrome and Facebook. I want to be able to do it for any app. Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3):

I've just recently come across this question, as I have been struggling with the same problem.

I have a potential solution which I've found which might help others. These instructions are for a Samsung Phone, but you may be able to find the equivalent options on Android.

I have a device that requires me to connect my phone to it via it's own hotspot. The hotspot the device creates doesn't have internet access, and because my cellphone thinks it is connected to a wifi network, it then refuses to use mobile data. I only want to use mobile data when connected to this ssid.

These are the steps I used which seemed to work:

1. Activate hotspot on device which does not have internet access.
2. In the connection settings connect to device.
3. Android then prompts you saying the current network does not have internet access.

```
    Connect just this time
    Always Connect
    Disconnect
```

**IGNORE THIS PROMPT!** Close the wifi connection app, and you should now have both a mobile connection and the network connection.

> **Note:**
> If you have already accepted one of these options, you can either:

- forget the network, and try this again,
- otherwise go to
  `Connections -> Wifi -> Advanced -> Switch to mobile data -> Network Exceptions` and delete the entry for the SSID in question.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me on my Note 20 on android 11

Comment: Works for me with a S21 on Android 13. [Edited by Moderator Firelord]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find an equivalent setting on Pixel 6.

Comment: Worked on my samsung galaxy S22 ultra